# Unable to scroll and select desired year from Calender in WebDriver Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I am trying to scroll the drop down and select an element via webdriver in python.
What Exactly I mean is, Drop down of "Calender" opens, scroll to "1990" year and then select it.
But unable to do it so.

```
def setUp(self):
    driverlocation ="/Users/new/Documents/Learning/Drivers/selenium-2.53.1/py/selenium/webdriver/chromedriver"
    os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = driverlocation
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverlocation)


def test_data(self):
    driver = self.driver
    url = "https://goods.theentertainerme.com/"
    driver.get(url)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    self.DateofBirth = driver.find_element_by_id("registrationform-date_of_birth")
    self.DateofBirth.click()
    Month = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div/div/select[1]/option[6]")
    Month.click()

    Year= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']//div/select[2]")
    YearList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']//div/select[2]")
    Year.click()
    Year1990= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']//div/select[2]/option[28]")
    driver.execute_script ("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",Year1990)
```

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: I don't think the double "//" are needed before the div, just one will suffice e.g. /div instead of //div

Comment: Its not that, you can use it. I have used in plenty of them and elements were founded.

Comment: Okay, that's fine, if they both work it may be best to make them all consistent. Also, are you getting any stack trace errors when you run the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Year1990 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div/select[2]/option[28]")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(Year1990).click(Year1990).perform()
```

Note: I've moved the double "//" before div to be one "/" e.g. /div instad of //div

Or...

```
Year1990 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div/select[2]/option[28]")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(Year1990).Perform()
Year1990.click()
```

For more information on Actions, see 7.2 of the following documentation http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html